# Mobile layout - Table Group by Rows or Columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

Build the table with

[image]

for mobile layout, need to change layout like below. Not sure whether collapsible by Rows or columns.

[image]

Can bring this layout via CSS? In case, we need to add margin top & bottom for "B" row is it possible to update via CSS?

Can please provide your valuable comments?

Thanks

```css
th, td{
      width: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td>2.2</td>
      <td>2.3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Do you use bootstrap?

Comment: yes.. we will use bootstrap

Comment: Can we dont use table html? can we use only `div`?

Comment: Its a content pop in CMS approach. So, we have limitations here to use only Table. Yes, we can bring this approach DIV easily as you said.

Comment: So you can code duplicate `table html`: 1 for PC, 1 for mobile :)